# How can I make a cable track follow a linear path while fixed at one end

Tags: animation, rigging

I am trying to create a cable track that follows a machine part along a linear path while fixed in position at the end. The cable track keeps moving too away from the machine part so that it looks like it is detatched.

Comment: hello could you please show some screenshots, maybe also share your file?

Comment: Basically, this is what I need to achieve but in blender

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kABLfvY7T4k&t=81s

Comment: are you talking about the machine at 1:50?